# Disabling Related Videos in YouTube iOS Helper using Swift

Tags: swift, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I know that to disable related videos we need to add `?rel=0` at the end of the YouTube URL. My question is how to do that in Swift?

1. I couldn't figure out a way to edit the HTML / JavaScript / Objective C files to get this to work.
2. I'm not sure how to pass the parameters using `loadWithVideoId` as it always fails to compile.

Any way out?

PS: I'm developing an iOS app that plays YouTube videos. I'm trying to disable related videos and I use the `YouTube-iOS-helper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [official documentation](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/50) as it says, "There is no development against Swift".

> Xcode 6.1.1 for iOS 8.1, this project will not compile.

The developers are still waiting for the new update. Till then you can use this third-party library https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player/

Or better you can wait for the new update from Google or Apple.

Comment: Strange .. cuz my project works! The only thing is .. I can't get the suggested video disabled. i.e. I don't know where to put the rel=0 clause.

The youtube code is in objective-c and I'm using a bridge

Answer (score 9):

Set the `rel` (related) key to false (`0`) in your playerVars dictionary:

```
let playerVars = [ "rel" : 0 ]
```

Then call `loadWithVideoId` as your normally would:

```
playerView.loadVideoWithId(videoId: "jCHE0Tjw6MA", playerVars: playerVars)
```

Comment: I can verify this works, however Youtube has changed it a bit.  Beginning Sept. 2018, setting `["rel": 0]` will not disable related videos, but it will restrict it to the channel the video came from.

[Youtube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add it to the playerVars. To simplify things in my Swift project I add this to directly to the YTPlayerView.m loadWithVideoId function so it would be:

```
- (BOOL)loadWithVideoId:(NSString *)videoId playerVars:(NSDictionary *)playerVars {
if (!playerVars) {
    playerVars = @{@"showinfo": @0}
}

NSDictionary *playerParams = @{ @"videoId" : videoId, @"playerVars" : playerVars };

return [self loadWithPlayerParams:playerParams];
}
```

Comment: Well that's already there but it doesn't work. So what I did instead was (like your code), I added the vars everywhere the player is being passed values. And it worked! Bad approach, but I needed something to get this done with.